# how can I fix OpenSSL configuration error in vs code terminal when running npm start

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

PS C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\basketball-scoreboard> npm start

> basketball-scoreboard@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

OpenSSL configuration error:
F4310000:error:80000002:system library:BIO_new_file:No such file or directory:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:67:calling fopen(C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\psqlODBC\etc\openssl.cnf, rb)
F4310000:error:10000080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:75:
F4310000:error:07000072:configuration file routines:def_load:no such file:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\conf\conf_def.c:179:

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.